# EditText getText() method

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm using getText() method on EditText() in setPositiveButton onClick() method and i have an RuntimeException when i execute my operation. Here is the code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
     switch(id) {
     case NICKNAME_DIALOG_ID:
         LayoutInflater nicknameInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         final View nicknameLayout = nicknameInflater.inflate
            (R.layout.nickname_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById
             (R.id.linearLayout_root));
         final EditText nickname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_nickname);   

            AlertDialog.Builder nicknameBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            nicknameBuilder.setView(nicknameLayout);                

            nicknameBuilder.setNegativeButton
               (R.string.nickname_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
               {                    
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                                                    int whichButton) {                      
                    SettingsActivity.this.removeDialog(NICKNAME_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });

            nicknameBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.nickname_dialog_ok, 
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                                                    int which) {
                    Editor editor = m_GameSettings.edit();
                    editor.putString
                            (VolimHrvatsku.GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME, 
                            nickname.getText().toString());//here's the error
                    editor.commit();
                    SettingsActivity.this.removeDialog(NICKNAME_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog nicknameDialog = nicknameBuilder.create();
            return nicknameDialog;
```

I once got a similar problem with button.getText() method, it was showing some int value, like this one.

---

I'm still having problem with getText().Here's the exception:

```
!SettingsActivity$4.onClick(DialogInterface, int) line: 110 
AlertDialog(AlertController$ButtonHandler).handleMessage(Message) line: 158 
AlertController$ButtonHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99    
Looper.loop() line: 123
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4633    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: 
not   available [native method] 
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 858  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 616 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace of the exception you are getting.

Comment: Your answer lies in your exception. Please post it.

Comment: Log Cat Details..Please

Answer (score 3):

i guess its a Nullpointer Exception since his View inflation seems off.

Try this line instead of yours

```
final EditText nickname = (EditText)nicknameLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText_nickname);
```

Comment: it worked, all i needed to do was handle onClick code with try-catch...and i put suggested line of code so thanks...

Comment: if it was a nullpointer you shouldnt catch that exception, since it is a either an error in your code or your workflow